# 5 boxes and 20 indistinguishable balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have 5 boxes, 20 indistinguishable balls. Probability of every possible arrangement of balls in boxes is the same. What is the probability that in the $k$-box we have at least $k$ balls, $k = 1,2,3,4,5$?

Does the second sentence tell us that it is only needed to write down all the possible series $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5)$ where $a_i$ is the number of balls in box $i$?

Answer (score 6):

Guide:

- Find the total number of possible arrangements if there are no further constraints. You can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) for this.
- For $k=1,2,3,4,5$ place $k$ balls in box $k$ so that $20-(1+2+3+4+5)=5$ balls are left. Now find the total number of possible arrangements if there are no further constraints and the number of balls to be placed equals $5$.

Answer (score 5):

If you have at least $k$ balls in the $k$-th box, that’s $\sum_{k=1}^5k=\frac{5(5+1)}2=15$ balls that need to be in those particular boxes, so you have $20-15=5$ balls left to distribute. Since there are $\binom{s+4}4$ ways to distribute $s$ balls over $5$ boxes, the desired probability is

$$
\frac{\binom{5+4}4}{\binom{20+4}4}=\frac{9!\cdot20!}{5!\cdot24!}=\frac3{253}\approx0.012\;.
$$